# What are good TR909 and TB303 default settings for electronica music?

Tags: sound, synthesis, drum, electronic-music

I enjoy house, techno, trance, disco, IDM, ambient, progressive and electronica sounds as french house, progressive house, acid house, warp records, guidance records, dragonfly records, bedrock records, border community, trax and easy street etc oldschool house and so.

I like the sound of the propellerheads rebirth and i want to recreate it with actual hardware and I already got a real Roland TR909 and the Cyclone TT303 bassbot which is a near perfect copy of the Roland 303. I also own a Roland Juno 60 so I have a pretty good base for vintage sounding dance music.

Now I wonder what good default setting for my TR909 you can tell me? There are infinitely many combinations and I like most of them. I look at how propellerheads rebirth have the knobs in deafult position when the rebirth program is starting and if I put me knobs on the TR909 like that then it sounds good but thing is that is always sounds good so say that I want a sounds of classic fat house like a Roland TR909 like in the rebirth program and a 303, I would like to know good basic beginner default settings for a Roland TR909 + a TT303 (the later which is a TB303 Replica)

Thanks!

Comment: This seems more music related.  I'm not sure if it would be on topic or not, but [Musical Practice & Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com/) might be more helpful if it is on topic.  I think it is borderline on fitting here as well, but I'm not sure the people on this site are going to be as skilled with settings for a keyboard as the musicians over on Music.

Comment: In my opinion, both of these devices sound pretty good "straight out of the box", so to speak. If I were you I wouldn't worry so much about which settings are supposedly good defaults. Rather, I'd just experiment and play about with them.

Comment: I'll add 'play around and take notes' - when you get a good sound, store it if the hardware permits, and take a photo of the controls if it doesn't. Once you think you have figured out what sounds it can make, record them and put the sound through Reason or other software to take it to the next level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several factors here, and not all may apply to your situation.

ReBirth is a really good simulation of 808s, 909s, and 303s, but they are a simulation of *ideal* versions of them. Your hardware setup is going to invariably differ to some degree. You do state that when you match the settings in ReBirth with your hardware, it sounds "good". This would imply that other patches on ReBirth would similarly sound as good on your boxes. So my suggestion would be to load some ReBirth files (there are tens of thousands on the net) that match the sub-genre you are looking to emulate and replicate those settings to get started. Then you can tweak to your preference.

If you don't mind spending a little more money, you could also get a decent compressor, which will really focus your sound and make it more punchy, but that may be a separate discussion altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I'm actually considering getting a hardware compressor for the kick and bass drumds (If my Nord Modular can't use it's compressor well).

Comment: Get a really good audio interface instead, with lots of inputs and outputs.  The sonic possibilities are much bigger.  Unless you want to spend lots of money, in which case, totally go nuts, you can get some really kickass hardware that way!